# Customizing dhtmlx in a project management application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, project, dhtmlx

I have an asp.net mvc4 web application for project management,
 in which i would like to use the lib `dhtmlx`  [official site](http://scheduler-net.com/LiveDemos.aspx)

my problem is how to customise it to add the list of tasks at left, a menu below it... 
is there a free example code to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that custom form's iframe prepends url with `'/'`,

e.g. if you attach view like following
`scheduler.Lightbox.SetExternalLightboxForm("SchedulerEventFormPartial", 640, 180);`

On the client iframe will have following value - `src="/SchedulerEventFormPartial"`

if you know about construction management software visit app.intellobuild.com